# PHP unserialized integer from 64-bit to 32-bit

Tags: php, serialization, architecture, integer-overflow

I have been trying to unserialize on a 32-bit server an object that was serialized on a 64-bit server. I have isolated my problem to an integer in the object. Here is a small reproduction of the problem.

On a 64-bit machine:

```
$i = serialize('20110510134021'); //i:20110510134021;
```

On a 32-bit machine:

```
$i = unserialize('i:20110510134021;');
```

Gives the error

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 16 bytes
```

Now I understand that those serialization method shouldn't be used for cross system data transmition. However, we are merely trying to migrate the data to another system, not use it actively for transfers. This is a one time thing.

I would think that this might be due to integer overflow, but even on the 32-bit server I can do something like

```
$i = 20110510134021;
echo $i;
```

And it will work fine. I'm guessing PHP integer types scale to some double type or something like that. But why doesn't it do that when it unserializes?

How can I unserialize those objects? If I can't, is there any way to convert them to something else? Finally, has anyone written a deserialize method in PHP itself? Or has details on the protocol? I could use that and have a custom case for those integers.

Thanks.

**Note:** I do not have access to the original data, only the serialized result.

Comment: Try using JSON as a transport instead, perhaps? That uses a completely different codebase and might not choke as hard on oversize ints when decoding the string on a 32bit system.

Comment: Can you cast this to a temporary string variable and serialize that instead? ($i = serialize('20110510134021'); is actually serializing a string..)

Comment: According to the PHP documenation integers scale to floats when they overflow: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php.

Comment: @MarcB I have inherited of this data. If it was my choice, I would have never used those awful serialization methods.

Comment: @jlb I do not have access to the original data, only the serialized result.

Comment: @Jan-Henk Ah, that explains why it works when just being declared. But it still won't unserialize though.

Comment: +1 for JSON. `json_decode` even has the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option to prevent the loss of precision with overflowing integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max integer on 32 bit system is `4294967296`;
`$i = 20110510134021;` works because PHP converts the variable to double.

So replace `i` with `d`

```
$i = unserialize('d:20110510134021;');
```

If you run this script, you will see the correct represenation of the variable on the system you are running (d: on 32 bit system, i: on 64 bit system):

```
$int = 20110510134021;
var_dump(serialize($int));
```

Comment: I was just about to try that. It works. I will have a regex go through my existing serialized strings and change them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is if you know that there is a chance that data serialized on 64 bit will be unserialized on 32 bit machine is to cast it to (double) before serializing.

Then it will be unserialized as a double, giving you more bits per integer than a standard 4-byte per integer (32 bits)

Once unserialized just work with that number as a double. In 99% of the cases this is a good solution. There is still a chance that for a very large number the number of bits allocated to the 'real' part on the number to a double on a 32 bit machine will not be enough. I think it's 56 bits, so the maximum integer is still significantly larger that the 32bits for the int type.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to the original data. I have inherited of the serialized form and need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$serialized = 'i:20110510134021';

if (preg_match('/i\:([\d]+)/', $serialized, $match))
{
    $unserialized = $match[1];
}
```

Comment: This is part of a much complex object containing arrays and strings and what not. I need to be able to unserialize that object as a whole.

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- deleted my comment.

Comment: By the way, is the original data a serialized array or object?